# Hidden commands on Windows

Tags: windows

Everybody has their secrets and Windows has them too.. I've been using these for a while and wanted to share them and I'd like to see some more I don't know yet.

1. To get to the 'Shut Down Windows' screen in Windows Vista is not straightforward too, and this is how I got there, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>**. This is useful too when you can't see your screen, and if you're lucky enough you can press, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>, and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to restart or shutdown a blind Windows (no screen).
2. Shutdown Windows Explorer: you have to get to the logoff screen then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and simultaneously **Cancel**, that will close Windows Explorer without ending the session. That helped me a lot when some Windows Explorer window goes crazy and doesn't want to respond. I think this has worked since Windows 95, but I'm not sure.

[image]

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, brings Task Manager to the focus and if it's not running it starts it, this is helpful when you have Windows Explorer closed (the point 1) and want to start a new one, going to file / new task, and running 'explorer'.

Comment: You should really have your tricks as answers so they can be included in the voting

Comment: You may be right but I just placed these as samples of what I wanted to be exposed here.

Comment: shutdown: (start > run > shutdown -s -t 0). Reboot: (start > run > shutdown -r -t 0)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure these are properly documented anywhere official, but I'm a big fan of the Windows Key shortcuts:

- Windows key alone - Start menu (follow this by shortcut keys to access the start menu with the keyboard - U to shut down, for example)
- Windows key + Pause/break - System control panel
- Windows key + R - Run
- Windows key + L - Lock the computer
- Windows key + E - Open new explorer window
- Windows key + D - Show desktop
- Windows key + F - Find
- Windows key + M - Minimize all
- Windows key + Shift + M - Restore all

Edit: I guess they are [documented somewhere official](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) after all.

Comment: +1 for Windows key D, the best shortcut noone knows about

Comment: Knew about all of these, except Windows+Pauze/Break. Nice one!

Comment: Nice thing about Windows+D is it toggles desktop view. Hit it again to restore your previous view.

Comment: When I did Pause/break on Win XP SP 3 it opened the System Properties window.

Answer (score 12):

[Bring Misplaced Off-Screen Windows Back to Your Desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/) is a classic in this time of "double screen programming", especially when you must access your double-screen computer from a one screen remote desktop.

> The application is running. You can see it in the taskbar, but you can't see it on the screen, because it still thinks it's running on the secondary monitor.
>   You try and use right-click, Move, but that doesn't do anything, and the window doesn't move anywhere. You end up rebooting and cursing Microsoft.
>
> There's a simple trick to get around this.
>   First make sure you've alt-tabbed to the window, or clicked on it once to bring it into focus.
>   Then right-click on the taskbar and choose Move

[image]

> At this point, you should notice that your cursor changes to the "Move" cursor, but you still can't move anything.

[image]

> Just hit any one of the arrow keys (Left, Right, Down, Up), move your mouse, and the window should magically "pop" back onto the screen.
>
> Note: **For keyboard savvy people, you can just `ALT-TAB` to the window, use `Alt+Space`, then `M`, then `Arrow key`, and then move your mouse.**

Comment: I love this technique, I use it all the time mostly when I switch my laptop from my desk in my office, where I have a docking station, and home where I dont and monitors are placed in different spots. Sadly there are some apps like gtalk that doesn't allow to move them this way... sad really... have to shut it down and start it again...

Comment: +1 This is a great one. I was really proud of myself when I figured this one out and still use it all the time.

Comment: @lc: Me too! I felt like a super hacker when I discovered it back on Windows 95.

Comment: I use a mouseless variation of this technique, ALT+SPACE, select move.

Comment: I use it all the time too, it feels more like a glitch than a feature but it is sooo handy!

Answer (score 3):

[Using Check Boxes to select multiple items within Windows Explorer](http://www.watchingthenet.com/add-check-boxes-in-vista-windows-explorer-for-selecting-multiple-folders-and-files.html).

This is really useful if you want to use single-click navigation rather than double click in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I THOUGHT this was cool, but then it wasn't AS COOL.  I still end up holding CTRL.

Answer (score 2):

For shutting down my machine I use <kbd>Start</kbd> , <kbd>U</kbd> , <kbd>U</kbd>. It depends on if you have anything that starts with `U` in your start menu or not, the above is for if you don't.

If you do have one, say `uTorrent`, in your frequently used programs area of the start menu, then you type: <kbd>Start</kbd> , <kbd>U</kbd> , <kbd>U</kbd> , <kbd>Enter</kbd> , <kbd>U</kbd>

The last <kbd>U</kbd> can be changed to either <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>.

Otherwise, I love <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>Start</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Start</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and the like.

I'm truly amazed by how many people CANNOT REMEMBER <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> no matter how many times a year you tell them. The problem seems to be in holding <kbd>alt</kbd> down to tab through the apps.

Answer (score 1):

I recently took the time to learn these keyboard shortcuts - pretty good when I am editing some text.

- Alt+Space+x (Maximise window with keyboard)
- Alt+Space+n (Minimise window with keyboard)

Lesser known ones are

- Alt+Space+m (Move window with arrow keys, press enter when done)
- Alt+Space+s (Change size of window with arrow keys, press enter when done)
- Alt+Space+r (Un-maximise window with keyboard)

Of course these shortcuts have been around for a long time.  In conjunction with Alt+Tab or Win+Tab, it just can come in handy when you are editing some text and don't want to take your keys off the keyboard.

Comment: I think you mean "Alt+Space, x" etc, but yeah, these are good.

Comment: You can do it either way.  Depends what your fingers are good at I think, but Alt+Space+x feels a bit more like it's a single key combination :)

Comment: alt-space, M: Comes in handy when a window is active and focused but out of view or covered.

Comment: I use Alt, Space, X.

Answer (score 1):

- Winkey+down to minimize, or if already maximized, restore
- Winkey+right, maximize to right half
- winkey+left, maximize to left half
- Winkey+up, uh, well, guess what that does,

Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows XP, if I recall, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> will bring up the task manager, even when it would normally bring up the dialog asking if you want to log off.

Comment: Control+Shift+Esc, and it's much older than XP :)

Answer (score 0):

Win-Shift-Left and Win-Shift-Right.

Moves windows to the next monitor over in their respective directions. Doesn't work too well when you have [two rows of three monitors](http://www.zi255.com/Post.aspx?Title=home+computer+lab+pictures), but I digress :)