# Hidden Features of Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Following in the rich tradition of [hidden commands in Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/4464/hidden-commands-on-windows), what are the hidden or not well publicized features in Windows 2008?

As always with these polls, please list one feature per answer.

For other 'hidden features' of other technologies and tools:
[Hidden Features of Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/2817)
[Hidden Features of PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/questions/2071) 
[Hidden Features of Oracle Database](https://serverfault.com/questions/3732)
[Hidden Features of Solaris/OpenSolaris](https://serverfault.com/questions/17468)
[Hidden Features of SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/14195)
[Hidden Features of IIS (6.0 / 7.0)](https://serverfault.com/questions/32012)

Comment: Community wiki please.

Comment: No need to list the hidden features articles - that's what the tags are for.  ;)

Comment: This question is similar to the "Hidden Features of" suite on stackoverflow. It gave birth to a real gold mine of information. I hope we can do the same here...

Comment: Including R2 (this summer) or excluding it?

Answer (score 3):

Boot from [VHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format)).

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/c7189892-ba70-4348-a952-79c50317ecc9/

Answer (score 2):

[Enable the Vista Aero theme](http://www.videotutorialzone.com/operating-systems/windows-server-2008/windows-server-2008-enabling-the-vista-aero-theme-and-programs.html) in Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Why? All it would do is leech up more resources than it needs to.

Comment: @Charlie: http://www.win2008workstation.com/ - Use Windows Server as your workstation.

Comment: Or terminal services but I guess it needs 2008 R2 to work over RDP